# What is probability it will rain tomorrow given it is sunny today?

Tags: probability, bayesian

Given that today is sunny.
What is probability that tomorrow will rain?

I'm not sure if this is the correct way or even if this question has enough info to start Bayes' Theorem discussion.

What elements am I missing if I am?

If I'm not. Is it just a 50% chance that it will rain tomorrow given today was sunny?

Basically 1 of 2 possibilities.

Thanks!

---Edit

So now that I know there needs to be more info.

Given that it has rained 6 of the 9 days. Not consecutively.
What is the probability it will rain again today? 
Is this enough information or would one need more?

Comment: It lacks a lot of information. What is the probability of being sunny or raining? Are the probabilities on two days independent?

Comment: Let $X$ be the weather today and $Y$ be the weather tomorrow. States of the weather: $0$ no rain (i.e. sunny) $1$ rainy. You're asked: $\Pr(Y=1|X=0)$ which equals $\frac{\Pr(Y=1\cap X=0)}{\Pr(X=0)}$. The problem therefore must give you enough info to compute the 2 probabilities in this fraction.

Comment: Looks as if this may be a piece of a problem on Markov Chains. Don't see how to answer with what you give. // Edited your problem. 'Bayes' was the person's name. Please edit again with more info if you have it.

Comment: @yumero I updated the problem. Do I have enough info now? If not what other info would I need?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any information linking those two days together, we can treat either days as a set and the question becomes "given bag A is filled with blue marbles, what is the probability that bag B is filled with red" the only information we have is that bag A is filled with blue marbles.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question with some info. Would love your thoughts on this. Thanks!